# Type overflow in project euler #5

Tags: f#

I am trying to solve the project euler #5:

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>
> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

Here is my code:

```
open System

let rec gcd a b =
    match b with
        | x when x = 0 -> a
        | _ -> gcd b (a % b)

let lcm a b = (a * b) / (gcd a b)        
let result = Seq.fold lcm 1 [1..20]

[<EntryPoint>]
let main(args : string[]) =
    printfn "result = %d" result 
    0
```

It works fine with numbers [1..19], but I get the wrong result with numbers [1..20].
I was trying to find out the reason of error and find that:

```
$ Seq.fold lcm 1 [1..19]
232792560 // right
$ lcm 232792560 20
18044195 // wrong
```

It looks like the type overflow. How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other solution is to redefine slightly the lcm function

```
let lcm a b = let m = b / (gcd a b) in a * m;;
```

Since you multiply by slightly smaller numbers, it won't overflow. Euler problems are also about mathematics :p

Answer (score 7):

Use `BigInt`, an integer type which won't overflow. If you replace `0` with `0I` (the `I` suffix is used for `BigInt` literals) in `gcd`, then both `gcd` and `lcm` will be infered to work with `BigInt`s instead of `int`s.

Comment: Instead of step 1, you could also just replace `0` with `0I`.

Comment: @Ramon Snir - indeed, I'm going to modify my answer to suggest that instead, since you can't have recursive inline functions anyways.

Answer (score 1):

In other languages, it's possible to work with 4-byte integer until it overflows, then the run-time upgrades your integer, and proceeds as planned.

I wonder if we could do the same thing in F#, to optimize performance.

Comment: For fun, try calculating 3^N, and print the values.  In Ruby.

Comment: You could do the same thing in any language but the performance is awful. Integer overflows are so rare in practice that it is not worth sacrificing the performance characteristics of all integer arithmetic for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370581.aspx) instead of the literal 0. This way the gcd function and thus the lcm function are generic and will work with any numeric type. Here a solution using int64:

```
module Problem5 =
    let rec greatestCommonDivisor a b  = // Euclidean algorithm
        if b = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero then  a 
        else greatestCommonDivisor b (a % b)
    let leastCommonMultiple a b  = (a * b) / (greatestCommonDivisor a b)
    // Take the least common multiple of all numbers from 1 to 20.
    let solution = [1L..20L] |> List.fold leastCommonMultiple 1L
```